# Реакция браузеров на "em" и "alt" у изображения

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть не замысловатая разметка:

```
<header>
    <a href="#" class="menu-button"></a><img scr="logo.svg" class="logo" title="logo">
</header>
```

к ней прилагаются стили:

```
header {
 font-size: 8px;
 height: 12.5em; /* 100px */
}
header > * {
 display: inline-block;
 height: inherit;
}
.menu-button {
 width: 11em; /* 88px */
}
.logo{
 font-size: 4em; /* 32px */
 position: relative;
 top: 1em; /* 32px */
 width: 6em;  /* 192px */
}
```

В Chrome результат ожидаем,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот в Firefox, что-то пошло не так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И собственно вопрос, почему так происходит?

P.S. Соль еще в том что если убрать атрибут `alt` FF разметит как надо, т.е. как в хроме

Comment: вы используете [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman нет, использовал reset.css, но тут то по идеи все должно поддерживаться, не IE все таки, к слову который вообще не понятно что делает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`em` расчитывается от дефолтного размера шрифта (по букве m). Проверьте, что за размер стоит по умолчанию.

`inline-block` предусматривает разное выравнивание. Раз оно прямо не задано, возможно ФФ и Хром выравняли по-разному

Comment: по поводу em не согласен https://habrahabr.ru/post/280125/

Comment: Спорить не буду. Убедитесь, что вертикальное выравниване блочно-строчных элементов одинаково или пропишите его в стилях принудительно.

Comment: То что надо. Хотя это немного странно ибо reset.css его устанавливает

Answer (score 1):

Потому что браузеры по разному воспринимают дробные значения. Сhrome округлил до меньше значения, FF - до большего.

Comment: в FF отступ в 2 раза больше, странно он округляет